# Forcing cache clear on Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: caching, google-search-console

I am trying to use the Google Webmaster Tools - data highlighter - to work on my site. I have a popup on there that was getting in the way so I disabled it. Added cache busting code to my js/css (i.e. ?v=datetime), etc. The popup is def gone but webmaster tools is holding on to hold html and wont update it so the cache busting doesnt work.  Any ideas how to force it to reload the site?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask similar questions there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you’ve recently made changes to a URL on your site, you can update your web page in Google Search with the Submit to Index function of the Fetch as Google tool. This function allows you to ask Google to crawl and index your URL.

See more in our Help Centre article titled [Ask Google to re-crawl your URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en)